# How to configure cascade type in JPA for many to one relationship?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, spring-data-jpa

I'm relatively new to the Hibernate Java persistence framework and I'm trying to understand how Cascade types work.

I have two tables, one is Assignment and the other is Student.
The assignment table has an assignmentNumber column, assignmentDescription column, assignmentGrade column and studentNumber column (which is a foreign key in the Student column).

```
Assignment|
-------

- assignmentNumber
- assignmentDescription
- assignmentGrade
- studentNumber

Student |
-------
- studentNumber
- studentFirst
- studentLast
```

There is a many-to-one relationship between the Student and Assignment tables as a student can be assigned multiple assignments. So in the AssignmentEntity class, I have the following setup:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ASSIGNMENT")
public class AssignmentEntity {

@Column(name = "assignmentNumber")
private Long assignmentNumber;

@Column(name = "assignmentGrade")
private String assignmentGrade;

@Column(name = "assignmentDescription")
private String assignmentDescription;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "studentNumber")
private StudentEntity studentEntity;
```

And in the StudentEntity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class StudentEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "studentNumber")
private String studentNumber;

@Column(name = "studentFirst")
private String studentFirst;

@Column(name = "studentLast")
private String studentLast;
```

Here's what I'm having trouble with: What do I change the cascade type to so that if a student already exists, there won't be a new entry when I do a save on a new assignment? I want to insert into the student table only if an assignment is saved with a new student that does not yet exist in the Student table.

Comment: To be clear, I also want to make sure that if I delete a an assignment, the students associated with that assignment will NOT be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

JPA is already doing that if used correctly. You don't describe how you are creating your entity instances, but here is how it should look like (for an already existing student):

1. Load the `Student` form the `EntityManager`/repository
2. Let the `Assignment` reference that instance.
3. Profit.

The key is not to create an instance of `Student` by calling `new` and setting its `Id`.

Comment: Would that also work if I wanted to delete an assignment but make sure that the student doesn't get deleted along with it?

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't use `CascadeType.ALL`. See https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/